# remove elements from list based on index in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe

How to remove elements from list based on index range in pandas Dataframe.

suppose DataFrame is like

```
df:

    values           size
0  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]    2     #delete first 2 elements from list
1  [1,2,3,4]          3     #delete first 3 elements from list
2  [9,8,7,6,5,4,3]    5     #delete first 5 elements from list
```

Expected Output is

```
df:

    values           size
0  [3,4,5,6,7]        2
1  [4]                3
2  [4,3]              5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension with indexing:

```
df['values'] = [i[j:] for i, j in zip(df['values'], df['size'])]
print (df)
            values  size
0  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]     2
1              [4]     3
2           [4, 3]     5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `df.apply`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"values": [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3,4],  [9,8,7,6,5,4,3]], "size": [2, 3, 5]})
df["values"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["values"][x['size']:], axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   size           values
0     2  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
1     3              [4]
2     5           [4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` in base Python, you could do

```
dat['values'] = pd.Series(map(lambda x, y : x[y:], dat['values'], dat['size']))
```

which returns

```
dat
Out[34]: 
            values  size
0  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]     2
1              [4]     3
2           [4, 3]     5
```