# Python: Delete items selected by index in all lists in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datfarme containg lists in every row

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Text": [[1,2,3,4,5], ['abc','bcd','cd','d','e'],  ['a',1,'de',3,'fg']]})
O [1,2,3,4,5]
1 [abc,bcd,cd,d,e]
2 [a,1,de,3,fg]
```

and so on.

```
result should look like this:
0 [3,5]
1 [cd,e]
2 [de,fg]
```

This is also the only column in the dataframe, therfore i cannot use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496684/remove-elements-from-list-based-on-index-in-pandas-dataframe)
So the task is to delete the first 2 and the 3rd item (with 0 indexing) -> only 2nd and 4th item should remain
It is important to delete them due to computation speed.

If i only had the lists i would say `del x [0:2]` and then again delete the "3rd" entry
I tried to creat a for loop which didnt work

```
for indedx,rows in df.iterrows():
del df.Text [0:3]
```

yields 'slice(0, 3, None)' is an invalid key

then i read a little about the pop method and tried this
`df.Text = df.Text.apply(lambda x: x.pop[0:3])` (since the lambda method worked for a split function)
and this gives me: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: you need `df['second_col'].str[-1]`

Comment: @lmo now it works

Comment: what exactly do you mean?

Comment: yes your right that was imprecise, have edited the question

Comment: @user10395806 the question asked for only the last element hence I suggested the same. Now it is edited

Comment: @anky_91 as i said the question was imprecise, thats why i edited it, now it should be clear what I need to do

Comment: Here is one way to go: `df.Text.map(lambda x : [x[2:][0], x[2:][2]])`. It does not delete, but performs multiple subsets.

Comment: could you please explain how it works concretely so i could apply it on different sets of problems too?

Comment: Briefly, the `map` method in pandas applies a function to every element of a series/dataFrame. `lambda` is a one-off function creator. The first `[` starts a list. the second subsets, keeping the second, third, and fourth elements. The next `[` selects either the second or fourth (original) elements.